# Does an inequality stay true after rooting

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, exponentiation

I have a very simple question but can't seem to find the answer for it.
If I have an equation like so:

$\|z-w\|^2 \ge (\|z\|-\|w\|)^2$, where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers and $\|\|$ is the modulus

Would the inequality (bigger or equal) stay true if I root them both? So would

$\|z-w\| \ge \|z\|-\|w\|$ still hold?

Comment: If your function is monotonic and increasing then $x>y \implies f(x) > f(y)$ then you can apply it to both sides of the inequality without upsetting things.  However, it is worth noting that  $\sqrt {(\|z\| - \|w\|)^2}= |\|z\| - \|w\||$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that
$$0\leq a \leq b$$
implies
$$\sqrt a\leq \sqrt b.$$
In your case you should be a little bit more careful as $\sqrt{(\|z\|-\|w\|)^2}=|\|z\|-\|w\||$, which can be $\|z\|-\|w\|$ or $\|w\|-\|z\|$. But since absolute value is the bigger of the two, your inequality holds anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $a^2\ge b^2$ does not imply $a\ge b$. However, if $a\ge0$, it does. This is the case here.

Comment: But $a^2 > b^2$ does imply that $|a| > |b|$